# Why couldn't Tarrlok resist another character's bloodbending?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

Why couldn't Tarrlok resist Amon's bloodbending?

In season 1 we have Tarrlok capture Korra and keep her locked in a metal box. Then Amon comes. When Tarrlok tries to bloodbend Amon, Amon resists. How come Tarrlok couldn't resist ***Amon's*** bloodbending?

Comment: I feel like you're answering your own question? Amon resists because his stronger/more skilled, ergo Tarrlok can't resist Amon. Are you asking for more than that? Perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

It's shown in the flashback episode that Amon was the stronger bender among the brothers.

Episode 11: Skeletons in the closet

> Tarrlok: A few years later, my father taught us to bloodbend anytime,
>   without the need of the full moon. We practiced constantly, and I
>   hated every minute of it. I had no stomach for manipulating helpless
>   animals. My brother, however, seemed to revel in this newfound power.
>   He was a prodigy, mastering my father's psychic bloodbending technique
>   by the time he was fourteen.